# Slick slider change opacity of first and last items

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I would like to change the opacity of the first and last items of the slick slider. Now, the center mode is set to true but I couldn't find CSS selector to make this happen. 
This is what I actually need:

[image]

Here is my current code.

**HTML**

```
   <div id="home_latest">
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <img src="default.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('#home_latest').slick({
     slidesToShow: 4,
     centerMode: true,
     dots: false,
     centerPadding: '220px',
     prevArrow: "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='slick_slider_nav slick_slider_nav_left'><img src='assets/img/slider-left-arrow.png'></a>",
     nextArrow: "<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='slick_slider_nav slick_slider_nav_right'><img src='assets/img/slider-right-arrow.png'></a>",
  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulna/9y2mfqtp/32/)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-active) {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Slick slider adds class `slick-active` on elements which are currently displayed/active on screen

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that doesn't work. Checkout fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rahulna/9y2mfqtp/32/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ab3um6xL/ I think issue is with `slidesToShow`, if you use any odd number it works fine, but in case of even number it fails

Comment: Yes, is there any way to use even numbers? I would like to display four. Thank you.

Comment: Using some custom CSS and javascript, I fixed this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey @rahul can i see your code? i also facing with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
#home_latest [aria-hidden="true"] {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it with this idea. I removed `centerMode` and left the `slidesToShow` as it is. Then, I applied padding to the "slick-list" container on left and right. It made the two inactive slides from left and right to display into the view. Then, I applied the above-mentioned class and it worked. I hope I have helped.